# Console.log convert array to comma separated value

Tags: javascript, arrays, console, console.log

**Test-1**

```
let myArray = [1,2,3]
function arrayCounter (array1) {
    console.log(`this is statement ${array1}`);
}
arrayCounter(myArray)
```

> **O/P => this is statement 1,2,3**

**Test-2**

```
let myArray = [1,2,3]
function arrayCounter2 (array1) {
    console.log("this is statement " + array1);
}
arrayCounter2(myArray)
```

> **O/P => this is statement 1,2,3**

**Test-3**

```
let myArray = [1,2,3]
console.log(myArray)
```

> **O/P => [1,2,3]**

In **test-1** and **test-2** expected O/P should be this is statement [1,2,3]

So, Why this is happening? I don't understand a scenario.

Comment: In test 1, the array is being converted into a string by javascript. The same goes for test 2. In test 3, the array object can be printed (doesn't need to be converted to a string) and thus is outputted as a full array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Test 1 and Test 2, you're concatenating the array with a string, which results in `Array.prototype.valueOf` being called, which returns the array items joined by commas, or `myArray.join(',')` So:

```
console.log(`this is statement ${array1}`);
```

is the same as

```
console.log("this is statement " + array1);
```

which is the same as

```
console.log("this is statement " + array1.join(','));
```

But in test 3, you're not `console.log`ging a string - you're `console.log`ging an *array*, so in the console, you'll see the `[` and `]`s indicating that the item being logged is an array.

Answer (score 1):

In test 1 & 2, your array is converted into a string:

```js
let myArray = [1,2,3]
console.log('' + myArray)
```